# How to dynamically generate richfaces tabs

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, richfaces

I'd like to know if it's possible to generate richfaces tabs dynamically *without* binding the component to the backing bean and looping through an array to populate it? I ask this because the `@ViewsScoped` [bug](http://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES-1492) will make such a solution useless in many cases. Primefaces provides dynamically generated tabs for a number of their container components but I'd really prefer to use richfaces here for a number of reasons. Thanks for your input.

Comment: You can bind the component to the `<rich:tabPanel>`, no need to iterate to show every `<rich:tab>`. As the bug link notes, you should use JSF 2.1.6 or superior to make it work.

Comment: What are the number of reasons to prefer RichFaces? PrimeFaces provides this particular feature and much more.